# Add large number of users to a Google group using PHP Google Directory API

Tags: php, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I need to add a large number of users to a Google Group using the PHP toolkit for the Google Directory API.

I am using: [`Members->insert`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert)

This works fine to add a user one at a time, but it is slow when you have to add a large number of users.

Is it possible to pass in an array to simply insert a bulk set of users at once?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that you linked to has a [best practices for sending batch requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch).

You should start there. If you have a specific issue with that, post a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

Reminder about the batch link above:

> This document is specifically about making a batch request by sending an HTTP request. If, instead, you're using a Google client library to make a batch request, see the client library's documentation.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!